# ios - how to localize the text for "more" in tab bar

Tags: ios, tabs

I'm having 7 tabs. and i'm able to localize text for all 7 tab titles
But when the app starts, by default only 4 tabs are showing with "more" tab as 5th one. I want to localize the text for "More". How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The label on the system-provided "More" tab bar item is localized automatically... if you have localized `InfoPlist.strings` for the user's language choice.

I created a new project using the "Tabbed Application" template and gave it several extra instances of `FirstViewController` to make it show the "More" tab.  I ran it in the simulator.  When I changed the simulator's language from English to Spanish, it did not translate the "More" label.

Then I clicked on `InfoPlist.strings` in the project, and in the File Inspector (on the right-hand side of the Xcode window), I added French as a localization.  The "More" label in the simulator was still in English (although my language was still set to Spanish).  Then I changed my language to French, and the "More" label was translated to "Autre".

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood. But in Info.plist file, can u give me the actual text to put (consider only french localization)

Comment: Can I change the name from more to something else?

Comment: Here's how to set a localized string for more tab bar item and the moreTableViewController itself

moreNavigationController.viewControllers[0].tabBarItem=UITabBarItem(title: String.localizeStringForKey("More"), image: UIImage(named:"more_active_30x30")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal), selectedImage: UIImage(named:"more_30x30")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal))
        
        moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.title = String.localizeStringForKey("More")

Answer (score 0):

You can set a localized string for more tabBarItem and the moreTableViewController itself!

```
//Here you can set the tabBarItem title and also the images when active and not active
moreNavigationController.viewControllers[0].tabBarItem=UITabBarItem(title: String.localizeStringForKey("More"), image: UIImage(named:"more_30x30")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal), selectedImage: UIImage(named:"more_active_30x30")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal))

// Here you can set the title of the moreTableViewController  
    moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.title = String.localizeStringForKey("More")
```